# Error returning vector of document objects using pyo3

Tags: python, mongodb, rust, bson, pyo3

Returning Vector of document objects from rust to python fails.

I have a struct and method implementation in rust as follows.

```
use mongodb::{
    bson::{Bson, Document},
    error::Error,
    sync::Client,
};
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
pub struct SampleStruct{
    docs: Vec<Document>,
}

#[pymethods]
impl SampleStruct{
    #[new]
    pub fn new() -> Self {...}

    pub fn a_method(&self, some_string: &str) -> Vec<&Document> {...}
}
```

The above fails with the following message

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<&bson::document::Document>: pyo3::callback::IntoPyCallbackOutput<_>` is not satisfied
   --> src/fail_demo.rs:55:1
    |
55  | #[pymethods]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `pyo3::callback::IntoPyCallbackOutput<_>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<&bson::document::Document>`
    | 
   ::: /home/demo/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pyo3-0.11.1/src/callback.rs:169:8
    |
169 |     T: IntoPyCallbackOutput<U>,
    |        ----------------------- required by this bound in `pyo3::callback::convert`
    |
    = note: this error originates in an attribute macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: I am experiencing a similar error. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: mongodb::bson::Document cannot be converted to python objects (ToPyObject). You should make a wrapper around &Document or Vec<&Document>.